# VIDEO - soundcodec AC3 (MKV)

Tags: html, audio, codec, mkv

Im trying to get a HTML page set up where a video is playing.

My video is an .mkv file. It works fine on Chrome, but I dont have any sound.
Audio codec is AC3.

My code:

```
<p><video src="video.mkv" type='video/x-matroska; codecs="a_ac3, avc"' autoplay controls onerror="failed(event)" ></video></p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wc2fn02s/

Comment: Is there any polyfill or something which makes it work in browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AC3 is not supported by Chrome due to licensing issues.

[No support for ac3 and dts](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=243861) - Current status: WontFix

[Media player silently ignores AC3 audio (pun intended).](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=367442)

The first link talks about third party plugins like [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/h265-hevc-player/dambgipgbnhmnkdolkljibpcbocimnpd) that can play it, though.