# HTML video tag - MKV/AC3 playback?

Tags: html, video, codec

I'm pretty new to web dev and I've been playing around with a little web app to play videos.

I've managed to get chrome to play an MKV format video using the video tag and not specifying a type attribute.

It has no audio though which seems to be because browsers don't support AC3 audio format.

Are there any workarounds/plugins you would recommend to play AC3 audio or is it impossible without converting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VIDEO - soundcodec AC3 (MKV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146541/video-soundcodec-ac3-mkv)

Answer (score 1):

I think this already have a good answer for you [VIDEO - soundcodec AC3 (MKV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146541/video-soundcodec-ac3-mkv)